# How to set variable into userEnteredValue field in Sheets ConditionalFormatRule

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, conditional-formatting

I am not able to pass a variable to 'my_condition_value' for TEXT_EQ.

```
v={"requests": []}
for i in range(0,len(my_condition_value)):
    v['requests'].append({
        'addConditionalFormatRule': {
    'rule': {
        'ranges': {
       "sheetId":document.getSheet("SheetName"),
      "startRowIndex": 3,
      "endRowIndex": df.shape[0]+1,
      "startColumnIndex": i+2,
      "endColumnIndex": i+3
        },
        'booleanRule': {
            'condition': {
                'type': 'TEXT_EQ',
                'values': [{
              "userEnteredValue": my_condition_value[i]
            }]
            },
            'format': {
                'backgroundColor': {
                    
          "red": 0,
          "green": 0.8,
          "blue":0.5
             }
            }
        }
    },
    'index': 0
}
})
```

It does not give any error, but it does not make the required change in the script either.

Comment: I thought that your script might be for python. But your tags have no `python` while `google-apps-script` is included. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: @Tanaike Exactly! I have added a python tag for the question. In my_condition_value I set a mode (most common value) value for the columns. So the goal is fields that have a mode (most common value) should be green, and other fields another color.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your goal. What language do you want to achieve your goal using? I thought that your script is for python. Do you want to convert the python script to Google Apps Script? I cannot understand the relationship between `python` and `google-apps-script` in your question. I apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike I got confused when creating the tags. The script is in python and uses google-sheets API. this is all

Comment: Thank you for replying. I understood that you wanted to achieve your goal using python. I think that your python script works. So I cannot understand your goal from `I am not able to pass a variable to 'my_condition_value' for TEXT_EQ.`. I apologize for my poor English skill. In order to correctly understand your goal, can you provide the sample input and output situations as the image? By this, I would like to try to understand it.